# Increasing one field in a MongoDB collection with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to increment a value in a collection in my MongoDB database through Mongoose. This is the demo code shown on the Mongoose website:

```
var conditions = { name: 'borne' }
  , update = { $inc: { visits: 1 }}
  , options = { multi: true };

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback)
```

And I have something like this:

```
var conditions = { "uniqueId" : itemId };
var update;
if(increase)
    update = {$inc : {inStock : 1}};
else
    update = {$dec : {inStock : 1}};
Item.update(conditions, update, {}, callback);
```

As you can see there is not much difference from the Mongoose's website code.

The problem is that when this piece of code is executed, I end up having in my collection one field called `$dec` (or `$inc`) which has an object as a field in the form `{inStock : 1}`. I just would like to increment the inStock entry of the collection. In the Schema I have:

```
var ItemToSell = new Schema({
    uniqueId : { type: Number, index: true }
  , name     : String 
  , type     : String
  , inStock  : Number
});
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) Make sure you're Mongoose is up-to-date. Older versions were very buggy on `Model.update` operations because Mongoose attempts to infer when you are merely passing a new object, in which case it turns your `update` object into a `$set` operation.

B) Try removing the empty `{}` from your function call. It is optional, and by passing an empty object rather than actual options, you may be confusing Mongoose into setting the `{ safe: false }` option, which could also be causing your problem. I have not checked the source code to confirm that that could be the issue, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By removing the empty `{}` I solved the problem which caused `{"$dec" : {"inStock" : 1}}` to be added to the collection. You were right also with the fact that I was using an old version of Mongoose BUT still I didn't solve the issue. Now it seems it doesn't do anything at all to the collection.

Comment: Ok I solved the issue. The `err` input of the callback function gave something now that I update my version of Mongoose. I discovered that `$dec` does not exists, thus to decrement I have to input a negative amount (`{$inc : {inStock : -1}}`). Thanks for giving a try though, it helped a lot!

Comment: do you know how to "**inStock**" as a parameter ?